# Android - User can't find apk, how to help them?

Tags: android, apk, shortcut

So a user downloads my apk app from my web server, not through google play. they will open the app from the notification bar and install it.

But what can I do if they erase the notification by mistake and need to find it manually? What can I do as the developer to help guide them? Is there any solution, perhaps automatically create app shortcut on download?

Comment: give that important information in your homepage.

Comment: Does your app have a launcher icon?

Comment: Depending on the browser used the apk may land in different download directories. So find out and put on homepage. But the easiest is download again.

Answer (score 0):

You can just have instructions on the download site telling them to use either an inbuilt file manager if their phone has one or download one like [Astro File manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.metago.astro&hl=en) to search for the apk